# Dialing Fallback with Twilo

Tags: twilio

I am working on my inbound TwiML. At one point I want to attempt to forward a call to my cell phone number.

So I got 5555555555 but I want to redirect to a different TwiML script if there is no answer or no human answer. For example if I do not answer and Twilo gets my Cell VM, I would instead want to have Twilo try someone else in another TwiML script rather than let them leave a message on my personal VM.

I know I can set it up so I have to press 1 to connect the call, then I am assuming if I don't press 1 it would continue processing the TwiML after  is this possible without requiring me to press 1?

Answer (score 4):

Joel from Twilio here.

The best way to do what you want is to use the call screening process that you describe ("press 1 to connect the call"). This is because automatically detecting voice mail is a very error prone process.

We have an in-depth [Call Screening HowTo](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/callscreening?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) on how to do this. Here's the overview:

Create a file called "attempt_call.php" on your web server that contains the following code (pay particular attention to the `$numbers` array on line 4):

```
<?php
// Set the numbers to call
$numbers = array("<number to call 1>", "<number to call 2>", "<number to call n>");
$number_index = isset($_REQUEST['number_index']) ? $_REQUEST['number_index'] : "0";
$DialCallStatus = isset($_REQUEST['DialCallStatus']) ? $_REQUEST['DialCallStatus'] : "";
header("content-type: text/xml");
// Check the status of the call and
// that there is a valid number to call
if($DialCallStatus!="completed" && $number_index<count($numbers)){
?>
    <Response>
    <Dial action="attempt_call.php?number_index=<?php echo $number_index+1 ?>">
        <Number url="screen_for_machine.xml">
        <?php echo $numbers[$number_index] ?>
        </Number>
    </Dial>
    </Response>
<?php
} else {
?>
    <Response>
        <Hangup/>
    </Response>
<?php
}
?>
```

Next, in the same location as the "attempt_call.php" file, create a file called "screen_for_machine.xml" with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather action="complete_call.xml">
        <Say>Press any key to accept this call</Say>
    </Gather>
    <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

Then, in the same location as the "attempt_call.php" file, create a file called "complete_call.xml" that contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather action="complete_call.xml">
        <Say>Press any key to accept this call</Say>
    </Gather>
    <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

Finally, set the "Voice Request URL" on your Twilio number to the full publicly available URL for the "attempt_call.php" file you created.

For more details, all of this code above is also available with mode in-depth explanation on the [Call Screening HowTo](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/callscreening?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) which is available on our website.